# how is program executed when there are 2 or more recursion function written togeather?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

how does line `return((count-2)+(count-1))` works in below `cpp` program?
ans of the given code is **-18** .how to know the ans without running the code
and out of two `function count(n-2)` and `count(n-1)` which one is called first and how is it decided?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int count(int n);
int main() {
    int n, m;
    n = 4;
    m = count(n);
    cout << m;
}

int count(int n)
{
    if (n<0)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return (count(n - 2) + count(n - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: For the result of the function call the order of evaluation doesn't matter.

Comment: @manni66 not in this case, but what if there were some global state that changes with each method call and affects the return value?

Comment: @DavidEtler that's an other question. In general: don't do that.

Comment: Would I be correct to assume it would vary from compiler to compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simply draw a binary tree to know the answer without compiling it. Just start breaking branch into two for count(n-1) and count(n-2) then add all leaves of trees.
Like if we took n as 4 it would be split as 3 and 2, Which would be two branch of 4. Similarly and recursively break nodes in to branch. 3 would be split into 1 and 2 so on. till leaves node is less then 0. In the end add value of all leaves to get the answers.

Answer (score 7):

There's no [*sequencing*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) between the left-hand and right-hand side of the `+` operator. So which one is evaluated first is unknown (and left up to the compiler).

The only way to figure it out is to step thought he code line by line, statement by statement, expression by expression in a debugger.

However, since each recursive call is not depending on any side-effects they can be executed independently of each other, and therefore the order doesn't matter as the result will always be the same.

Comment: You may want to add that if that call is recursive or not does not matter here.

Comment: how to know the answer without compiling it?

Comment: @SamihanJawalkar The same way as the program does it. You know that `count(4)` is `count(2) + count(3)`, so you figure out what `count(2)` and `count(3)` are and add them together.